# Generate Random Rectangles

Tags: java

So I'm creating a very simple platform game and I want to have the platforms generate randomly so that each playthrough is unique. However, I'm unsure of how to do this perfectly. I managed to get some working code that actually generates random rectangles on the screen, but I'm not sure how to make it so that the "character" can move around on them and won't fall through and what-not. Here's my code for everything so far. It isn't pretty at all right now, but I'll neaten it up when I know everything works. Thanks in advance for the help :)

P.S.  I also commented out the stuff related to the random rectangles, as they completely fill the screen and I can't see what's going on :P

Game.java

```
    public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public Rectangle character, floor;
    public int characterWidth = 24;
    public int characterHeight = 36;
    public int fps = 1000; //setting framerate 
    public int fallingSpeed = 1;
    public int fallingFrame = 0;
    public int floorHeight = 80;
    public int movementSpeed = 1;
    public int movementFrame = -1;
    public int movementFallingSpeed = 10;
    public int movementResetSpeed = 1;
    public int jumpingLength = 150; //# of pixels
    public int jumpingFrame = 1;
    public int jumpingCountFrame = 0;
    public int jumpingCountSpeed = fallingSpeed;
    public int xs = 0;
    public int ys = 0;

    public int keyJump = KeyEvent.VK_SPACE;
    public int keyLeft = KeyEvent.VK_A;
    public int keyRight = KeyEvent.VK_D;


    public boolean objectsDefined = false;
    public boolean falling = false;
    public boolean running = true;
    public boolean right = false;
    public boolean left = false;
    public boolean jumping = true;

    public Thread game;
    RandomRects ad[];
    Random rand = new Random();

    public Game(Frame f){
        setBackground(Color.black);

        defineObjects();

        game = new Thread(this);
        game.start();

        f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
                if (e.getKeyCode() == keyLeft ){
                    left = true;

                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == keyRight){
                    right = true;
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == keyJump){
                    if (!falling){
                        jumping = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
                if (e.getKeyCode() == keyLeft ){
                    left = false;
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == keyRight){
                    right = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void defineObjects(){

        character = new Rectangle((Main.width/2) - (characterWidth/2), (Main.height/2) - (characterHeight/2), characterWidth, characterHeight);
        floor = new Rectangle(-10, Main.height - floorHeight, Main.width + 10, floorHeight);

        ad = new RandomRects[rand.nextInt(200)];

        /*for(int count=0; count< ad.length; count++){
            int posX1=rand.nextInt(400);
            int posY1=rand.nextInt(400);
            int posX2=rand.nextInt(400);
            int posY2=rand.nextInt(400);

            Color rectColor= new Color(rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
            ad[count] = new ad(posX1, posX2, posY1, posY2, rectColor);

        }*/


        objectsDefined = true;

        repaint();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (objectsDefined){
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fill3DRect(character.x - xs, character.y - ys, character.width, character.height, true);
            g.fill3DRect(floor.x -xs , floor.y - ys, floor.width, floor.height, true);


        }

         /*for(int count=0; count<ad.length; count++){
             ad[count].draw (g);

         }*/
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running){

        //Character feet
        Point pt1 = new Point(character.x, character.y + character.height);
        Point pt2 = new Point(character.x + character.width, character.y + character.height);

        //Falling
        if (!jumping){
            if (fallingFrame >= fallingSpeed){
                if (floor.contains(pt1) || floor.contains(pt2)){
                    falling = false;

                }else{
                    character.y += 1;
                    falling = true;

                }

                if (falling){
                    character.y += 1;
                    //ys+=1;

                }

                fallingFrame = 0;

            }else{
                fallingFrame += 1;


            }
        }

        //Jumping
        if (jumpingCountFrame >= jumpingCountSpeed){
            if (jumping){
                if (jumpingFrame <= jumpingLength){
                    character.y -= 1;
                    //ys -=1;

                    jumpingFrame += 1;

                }else{
                    jumpingFrame = 0;
                    jumping = false;
                }
            }

            jumpingCountFrame = 0;
        }else{
            jumpingCountFrame += 1;
        }

        //Movement Speed Check
        if (falling){
            movementSpeed = movementFallingSpeed;

        }else{
            movementFrame += 1;
        }


        //Movement
        if(movementFrame >= movementSpeed){
            if (right){
                character.x += 1;
                xs +=1;
            }

            if (left){
                character.x -= 1;
                xs-=1;

            }

            movementFrame = -1;

        }else{
            movementFrame += 1;
        }

        fpsSetter();

        repaint();

        }   
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public void fpsSetter(){
        try{
            game.sleep(fps/1000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

RandomRects.java

```
    public class RandomRects {

    private int posX1;
    private int posY1;
    private int posX2;
    private int posY2;
    private Color rectColor;

    public RandomRects(int posX1, int posX2, int posY1, int posY2, Color color){
        this.posX1 = posX1;
        this.posX2 = posX2;
        this.posY1 = posY1;
        this.posY2 = posY2;
        this.rectColor = color;
    }

     public void draw (Graphics g){
         g.setColor(rectColor);
         g.fillRect(posX1,posY1,posX2,posY2);
     }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the inbuilt [geometry API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) it has functionality that allows you to paint and check for collesions...

Comment: Please create a [short, self-contained correct example](http://sscce.org/). This is way too much code for a question, no one will read all that. Even if I had time, on the principle I refuse to read code that calls its classes `aa`, `ab`, `ac`, `ad` (unless my boss forces me to).

Comment: @Amadan Sorry this is my first time making a post on here. I removed the first 2 classes, as they are irrelevant to the problem. I only called them aa, ab, etc. because I couldnt think of better names for them lol.

Comment: Well the first step would be to figure out what they do. For example, if a class is in charge of random rectangles, call it `RandomRect` or the like.

Comment: Naming things is an important skill for a programmer. Go ahead using nonce names if you intend to never cooperate with other programmers, and never maintain your code more than two months after you wrote it.

Comment: @Amadan Keep in mind, this game is more for me so I can improve my skills. Also, as I stated in the post, I am going to clean things up, which includes renaming the classes.

Comment: @AndrewG I was planning on renaming them later when I go through and clean up the code a bit.

Comment: You might have wanted to clean things up before posting here. As @Amadan said its quite hard to read. For example, why didn't you name `ad` to `MyRectangle` or `ColoredRect` or something like that when you created it? It makes it much easier to read, so when I see `ad` in your ac class's code I don't have to think about what I'm looking at.

Comment: Good. But naming them right the first time around is a good habit to get into. When you started writing the class `ac`, you must have had an idea what you wanted it to do. If during refactoring you find out another name fits better, of course you should rename it; but there should be no moment in time where you have an identifier `ac` unless it has to do with electricity. Short variable names such as `i` or `n` are permissible if their scope is at most five lines or so; anything else should have a descriptive name that a reader will understand the purpose of. Especially when you post on SO.

Comment: Also I have a comment about the question. If this is a classic platform game like Mario Bros, you most likely will want to preserve x and y positions for certain parts of your rectangles. For example, use the same Y position for the both the top points of a rectangle, so you know it will be flat. You can also offset the Y for the bottom points from the top points so the rectangle will be a fixed height. You might also want to make sure that all rectangles obey a minimum width requirement so there is something for your "character" to stand on that isn't one pixel wide or something awkward.

Comment: @Amadan I renamed the classes and updated the post

Comment: Great! Also all this can be found on the [Java Coding Conventions' Naming Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). The entire document is a great resource too!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need is to "imagine" moving the character; if the moved character would overlap with any of your rectangles ("collision detection"), prevent the move. If it doesn't, then confirm that the next position of the character is the moved one. You can use `Rectangle` method [`intersects()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).